# How to open Google Play to update the ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am having ionic app. Whenever there is update , I am just comparing the version installed on user's mobile and the version at server . If user is having older version then I want to show the user with prompt to update the app and once he/she clicks ok , I want to open play store so that he can update the app. Please guide

Kindly guide , please advice

Comment: i think if you use the normal links example `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en&gl=US` and open it from mobile, google will automatically redirct you to the application and i think same in app store `https://apps.apple.com/us/app/facebook/id284882215` should also be redirected to app store since their is already deeplinks in their apps..

Answer (score 0):

For this, I use Market plugin:

```bash
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-market
npm install @ionic-native/market
```

```js
import { Market } from '@ionic-native/market/ngx';

constructor(private market: Market) { }

...

this.market.open('your.package.name');
```